# How do I search and replace date in vi without affecting other numbers?

Tags: date, search, replace, wildcard, vi

The 4th colum in this date contains a date.
I want to search for every date that is prefixed with 2014 and replace it with 2013.
I don't want to alter the numbers in any other column where 2014 might appear also.
I'm having trouble using wildcards, could anyone please tell me the vi command to do such a thing?
Thanks very much

20140009,20140009,GSM-AHS,20101218132823,,46767807490,5302833,IA,D,POST,,N
20140009,20140009,GSM-AHS,20140119000900,,46767807490,5302833,IA,D,POST,N,N
2014001,2014001,GSM-AHS,20131012212112,,46730360076,3922720,HK,I,PRE,,N
2014001,2014001,GSM-AHS,20140119000900,,46730360076,3922720,HK,I,PRE,N,N
2014001,2014001,GSM-AHS,20140615210515,,46730360076,3922720,HK,I,PRE,N,N
2014001,2014001,GSM-AHS,20140617213108,,46730360076,3922720,HK,I,PRE,N,N
2014001,2014001,GSM-AHS,20140627150239,,46730360076,3922720,HK,I,PRE,N,N
2014001,2014001,GSM-AHS,20140705085247,,46730360076,3922720,HK,I,PRE,N,N
2014001,2014001,GSM-AHS,20140729075246,,46730360076,3922720,HK,I,PRE,N,N
20140012,20140012,GSM-AHS,20101221165213,13,46767674084,1,RO,O,PRE,,N
20140012,20140012,GSM-AHS,20130113025426,,46767674084,1,RO,O,PRE,N,N
20140016,20140016,GSM-AHS,20130728205747,20145,46767674542,5493416,OU,D,POST,,N
20140016,20140016,GSM-AHS,20140518005550,,46767674542,5493416,OU,D,POST,N,N
20140017,20140017,GSM-AHS,20131230033641,,46767807730,7810638,08,D,POST,N,N
20140020,20140020,GSM-AHS,20140518005550,,46767817323,1090680,OT,D,POST,N,N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your 3rd columns contain `GSM-AHS,` you can try

```
:%s/GSM-AHS,2014/GSM-AHS,2013
```

which will replace the first match only, not touching the rest.